# i want to run python code using python-shell lib in elasticbeanstalk

Tags: python, node.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

in node.js code run python code using python-shell lib in aws elasticbeanstalk

```
const PythonShell = require('python-shell');
const co = require('co');
const runPy = (text) => co(function* () {
const options = {
    mode: 'text',
    pythonPath: '',
    pythonOptions: ['-u'],
    scriptPath: '',
    args: [text]
};
return yield new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    PythonShell.run('./test.py', options, function (err, results) {
        //do something
    });
 })
});
```

error log is

```
{ Error: ImportError: No module named numpy
at PythonShell.parseError (/var/app/current/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:183:17)
at terminateIfNeeded (/var/app/current/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:98:28)
at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:88:9)
at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
```

I have a node.js server and I want to run python code using python-shell library in aws elasticbeanstalk. 
When I deploy the server, an error is generated. In the log says it cannot find python module (ex. numpy, networkx...)

How can I solved this problem?

Comment: Post code as well

Comment: yes i pasted my code

Comment: https://scipy.org/install.html